# apexcharts bar chart selection shading on click

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I am looking to disable or at least find how to modify Apexchart's bar chart "selection shader" when you click on a bar chart. you can see in the image that the bar selected will turn darker than the rest. i want to build on this (make it darker or lighter).. I searched through the ApexCharts documentation and tried implementing selection and a few others, but no luck:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
options = {
  states: {
    active: {
      filter: {
        type: 'none' /* none, lighten, darken */
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Docs: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/states/#active